# how to access auto increment id of any model using form in django?

Tags: python, django

models.py

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    state_province = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author, blank=True)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

forms.py

```
class Books(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('title', 'authors', 'publisher',)


class Authors(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email',)


class Publishers(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Publisher
        fields = ("id","name", 'address', 'city', 'state_province', 'country',)
```

views.py

```
def demo(request):
    form1 = Books(request.POST)
    form2 = Authors(request.POST)
    form3 = Publishers(request.POST)
    if (form1.is_valid() & form2.is_valid() & form3.is_valid()):
        form3.save()
        form2.save()
// Here I want to access id of just saved data of Model Publisher and Model Authors
        form1.cleaned_data['publisher'] = form3.data['id']

    return render(request, 'files/demo.html', {'form1': form1, 'form2': form2, 'form3': form3})
```

In Above code I want to save all data of all models in single view But errro is that Book model has ForenignKey relation with Publisher and Publisher doens't not have any unique data to identify the ID of just saved data. So My real question is that how can I access the Publisher and Author ID that data is saved using `

> form3.save() and form2.save()

`I'm very confused to save multiple model data with same time with handle forenignkey relation between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

save() returns the object, so you just need to do

```
publisher_obj = form3.save()
author_obj = form2.save()
book_obj = form1.save(commit=False)
book_obj.publisher = publisher_obj
book_obj.save()
book_obj.authors.add(author_obj)
```

and remove the 'id' from the form. You don't need it.

Comment: I got Error  "<Book: Book object>" needs to have a value for field "book" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.

Comment: Sorry, hard to write code without testing it, but seems like you got it